# Lookup value in one dataframe based on column name stored as a value in another dataframe

Tags: r, replace, match, data.table, lookup

Please see the reproducible (cut + paste) example below. The actual data set has over 4000 serial observations on 11000  people.  I need to create columns A, B, C, etc. showing the NUMBER of the "Drug" variables X,Y, Z etc. that corresponds to the first occurrence of a particular value of a "Disease" variable.  The numbers refer to actions that were taken with particular drugs (start, stop, increase dose etc.)  The "disease" variable refers to whether the disease flared or not in a disease that has many stages including flares and remissions.

For example:

```
Animal <- c("aardvark", "1", "cheetah", "dromedary", "eel", "1", "bison", "cheetah", "dromedary",     
"eel")
Plant <- c("apple_tree", "blossom", "cactus", "1", "bronze", "apple_tree", "bronze", "cactus",     
"dragonplant", "1")
Mineral <- c("amber", "bronze", "1", "bronze", "emerald", "1", "bronze", "bronze", "diamond",     
"emerald")
Bacteria <- c("acinetobacter", "1", "1", "d-strep", "bronze", "acinetobacter", "bacillus", 
"chlamydia", "bronze", "enterobacter" )
AnimalDrugA <- c(1, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19)
AnimalDrugB <- c(20, 1, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29)
PlantDrugA <- c(301, 302, 1, 304, 305, 306, 307, 308, 309, 310)
PlantDrugB <- c(401, 402, 1, 404, 405, 406, 407, 408, 409, 410)
MineralDrugA <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
MineralDrugB <- c(11, 12, 13, 1, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20)
BacteriaDrugA <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 , 7, 8, 9, 1)
BacteriaDrugB <- c(10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1)
dummy_id <- c(1001, 2002, 3003, 4004, 5005, 6006, 7007, 8008, 9009, 10101)


Elements <- data.frame(dummy_id, Animal, Plant, Mineral, Bacteria, AnimalDrugA, AnimalDrugB,          
PlantDrugA, PlantDrugB, MineralDrugA, MineralDrugB, BacteriaDrugA, BacteriaDrugB)
ds <- Elements[,order(names(Elements))]
ds  #Got it in alphabetical order... The real data set will be re-ordered chronologically


#Now I want the first occurrence of the word "bronze" for each id
# for each subject 1 through 10.  (That is, "bronze" corresponds to start of disease flare.)
first.bronze <- colnames(ds)[apply(ds,1,match,x="bronze")]
first.bronze

#Now, I want to find the number in the DrugA, DrugB variable that corresponds to the first            
#occurrence of bronze.
#Using the alphabetically ordered data set, the answer should be:
#dummy_id  DrugA  DrugB
#1...      NA   NA
#2...      2    12
#3...     NA    NA
#4...     4     1
#5...     5     6
#6...    NA    NA
#7...    7     17
#8...    8     18
#9...    9     2
#10...    NA    NA
#Note that all first occurrences of "bronze"
# are in Mineral or Bacteria.
#As a first step, join first.bronze to the ds
ds$first.bronze <- first.bronze 
ds

#Make a new ds where those who have an NA for first.bronze are excluded:
ds2 <- ds[complete.cases(ds$first.bronze),]
ds2


# Create a template data frame
out <- data.frame(matrix(nr = 1, nc = 3))
colnames(out) <- c("Form Number", "DrugA", "DrugB")  # Gives correct column names
out

#Then grow the data frame...yes I realize potential slowness of computation
test <- for(i in ds2$first.bronze){
    data <- rbind(colnames(ds2)[grep(i, names(ds2), ignore.case = FALSE, fixed = TRUE)])
    colnames(data) <- c("Form Number", "DrugA", "DrugB")  # Gives correct column names
    out <- rbind(out, data)
}
out

#Then delete the first row of NAs
out <- na.omit(out)
out

#Then add the appropriate dummy_ids
dummy_id <- ds2$dummy_id
out_with_ids <- as.data.frame(cbind(dummy_id, out))
out_with_ids
```

Now I am stuck.  I have the name of the column from ds2 listed as a value of Drug A, Drug B in the out_with_ids dataset.  I have search through Stack Overflow thoroughly but solutions based on match, merge, replace, and the data.table package don't seem to work.

Thank you!

Comment: Hi, +1 for the cut+paste example.  However, if you could please simplify the question a bit further, that will help us be able to more quickly post an answer

Comment: I'll try to simplify:  Basically df1 contains some variables whose values are the names of variables found in df2. I need to replace the values of those variables in df1 with the actual values found under the matching variable names on df2.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is data format. May I suggest you store it in "long" table, like this:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(dummy_id = rep(dummy_id, 4),
                 type = rep(c("Animal", "Bacteria", "Mineral", "Plant"), each = 10),
                 name = c(Animal, Bacteria, Mineral, Plant),
                 drugA = c(AnimalDrugA, BacteriaDrugA, MineralDrugA, PlantDrugA),
                 drugB = c(AnimalDrugB, BacteriaDrugB, MineralDrugB, PlantDrugB))
```

Then it is much easier to filter and do other operations. For example,

```
dt[name == "bronze"][order(dummy_id)]
```

Frankly I'm not sure I understand what you want to achieve in the end.